# jQuery this() issues

Tags: jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Axsjg/)

I must be doing something stupid, but I really can't figure this out, why is this script not console.log(ing) the text from the `<p>` tag?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Display Name:</label>
    <div>
        <p>The room that its in.</p>
        <span class="edit"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($('span.edit').length > 0) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        var elem = $(this).prev();
        var text = elem.text();
        console.log(text);
        elem.html('<input type="text">' + text + '</input>');
    });
}
```

Comment: What's `this` in the code?

Comment: Oh, hmm, i thought it would be $('span.edit), that's probably my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript isn't block scoped; what do you expect `this` to be?

Fixed:

```
if ($('span.edit').length > 0) {
    $('span.edit').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this).prev();
        var text = elem.text();
        console.log(text);
        elem.html('<input type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    });
}
```

**edit:** updated `html()` contents to correct input gaffe

Comment: Any thoughts on why the closing tag of my input is not going into my html?

Comment: @watson - An input has no closing tag ?

Comment: thanks @nbrooks; fixed. We both know I know that. Time for another cup of coffee!

Answer (score 1):

My guess here is that `this` should be referring to `span.edit` selector.

This is not the case.

You don't need to check if `span.edit` has a length. If there are no matches, the click event will simply not be bound to any elements.

Therefore your code can be simplified like this:

```
$("span.edit").click(function(){
     var elem = $(this).prev();
     var text = elem.text();
     console.log(text);
     elem.html('<input type="text">' + text + '</input>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because this doesn't refer to the span. However in the below code it will be bound to the span:

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Axsjg/2/)

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).prev('p');
    var text = elem.text();
    elem.html('<input type="text">' + text + '</input>');
});
```

also, you do not have to check for the length as the span is always present on the page (atleast in the fiddle). Furthermore if it wasn't present, the event just wouldn't be bound.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is unnecessary—if there are no such elements, the click handler does nothing. Putting the handler inside the `if` doesn't change the scope of `this` to match that element either. Just target the `<span>` directly:

```
$('span.edit').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).prev();
    var text = elem.text();
    console.log(text);
    elem.contents().unwrap().wrap('<input type="text">');
});
```